# Regex remove duplicates

Tags: regex

I have a bit of a problem trying to remove duplicate strings in regex. Here are some example strings, followed by my code and then followed by what im getting vs what I want.

Examples

```
Test1; Test3; Test3; Test12
Test3; Test3
```

My code

```
\b(\w+); (?=.*\b\1;?) replaceing with blanks
```

Gives me

```
Test3; Test12
Test3
```

I want

```
Test1; Test3; Test12 
Test3
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Is your code really `(?=. *\1,?)` ? I think it's far more likely that you've used `(?=.*\1;?)`.

Comment: ...And now you've just changed it again. Please clarify exactly what you're running.

Comment: Sorry mis typed updating now

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `Test1` also matches part of `Test12`. You already used [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), just not in all the necessary spots:

```
\b(\w+)\b; (?=.*\b\1\b)
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/rVcTH6/1).